# Why am I getting a 200 response even though data isn't being stored in the database?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

For starters - My Laravel and React.js codebase are separated.

When I login in Postman with login endpoint followed by uploading name of the file with another endpoint (both of them POST requests), the `filePath`, `email` and `user_id` are stored successfully in the db.

However, when I do try this on the browser - I get a `200` but oddly enough, nothing's stored in the db.

In Postman, it somehow detects what user's logged in which allows me to store the aforementioned information into the DB without problems.

What am I doing wrong here in my frontend and backend code that's not allowing me to do this on the browser?  I've hit a wall with this one and not sure where to from here.

FYI:  The `dd($user);` returns the correct information.

Please let me know if you need more information :)

Here's my `Upload.js` file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null,
            id: null,
            email: ''
        };
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Inside componentDidMount()");
        let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
        let email = localStorage.getItem("email");
        this.setState({
            id: id,
            email: email
        })
        console.log(id);
        console.log(email);
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files[0] }, () => this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    fileUpload(file) {
        const formData = new FormData(document.getElementsByClassName("form")[0]);
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token").slice(13,-8);

        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(this.state.id);
        console.log(this.state.email);
        console.log(file.name);
        formData.append('file',file);

        const headers = {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/wall-of-fame', formData, {headers})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form encType='multipart/form-data' id="login-form" className="form" >
                <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.onFormSubmit}>Upload</button>
            </form>
        );
    }

}

export default Upload;
```

Here's my `FileUploadController.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $user = Auth::user();

//        dd($user);
        if($user) {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $email = Auth::user()->email;
            $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
            $data = [
                'file_path' => $filePath,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'email' => $email
            ];
            DB::table('mydb.photos')->insert($data);
        }

        return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```

Here's my `api.php` file:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    Route::post('wall-of-fame', 'FileUploadController@store');

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
        Route::get('wall-of-fame', 'FileUploadController@fileUpload');
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by `when i try to do this on the browser`.  Are you just entering the route url for the `post` request in the browser?  This will just be converted to a `GET` request won't it and which would be a `200` unless you hit a 404 route?  Or have i misunderstood what you mean?

Comment: @jameson2012 Oh, I meant when I try it as if I'm the user on the client side.  Login > Upload a file.

Comment: In general postman adds headers automatically (look at the hidden headers) as that is what you are probably missing. 

If you are using `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` then postman automatically adds a boundary to it. If you don't specify the `content-Type` then postman probably set it to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Oh and some file hosting services require the "key" to be "file" to successfully post the file. Jira for example gives a 200 OK if you upload a file with a `key!="file"` (and postman automatically sets it :P)

Comment: @GregM yep, I've already set the "key" in Postman to "file" already.  I'm so stumped.  How can I detect which user's logged in on the client side so that it knows which data to store in the db?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The problem was in the `routes/api.php` file.

The **order** of the routes, and the **route names** matter.

Make sure that your `post` route has a **unique name** or that it's **on top** of similar other routes if its name is duplicated.